# How to include .proto files having mutual dependency

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc, proto

I have two .proto files, which has two packages that have mutual dependency.

`a.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "b.proto";

package a;

message cert {
    string filename = 1;
    uint32 length = 2;
}

enum state {
    UP = 1;
    DOWN = 2;
}

message events {
    repeated b.event curevent = 1;
    uint32 val = 2;
}
```

`b.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "a.proto";

package b;

message event {
     a.cert certificate = 1;
     a.state curstate = 2;
}
```

When I try to generate cpp files, following error is seen

`# protoc -I. --cpp_out=.  b.proto
b.proto: File recursively imports itself: b.proto -> a.proto -> b.proto`

How can this be achieved ?

Note : protoc version used is `libprotoc 3.3.0`

Comment: If it was a mutual dependency then moving the shared part to c.proto would work - however, looking at your scenario, I don't think that can be resolved short of moving everything to one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proto compiler won't let you include circular dependencies. You will have to organize your code such that there aren't any recursive imports. One organization of your sample code above could be:

a.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package a;

message cert {
    string filename = 1;
    uint32 length = 2;
}

enum state {
    UNDEFINED = 0;
    UP = 1;
    DOWN = 2;
}
```

b.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "a.proto";

package b;

message event {
    a.cert certificate = 1;
    a.state curstate = 2;
}

message events {
    repeated event curevent = 1;
    uint32 val = 2;
}
```

Your `events` type doesn't use anything from `a.proto`, and also uses `event` type from `b.proto`. It makes sense to move it to `b.proto`.

Comment: But when you compile `a.proto`, you won't have `b.proto` included. So if you compile `b.proto` you will have `a.proto`, but once you got `c.proto`, `d.proto` and `e.proto`, you'll be running into problems again.